# How to create AssemblyQualifiedName from TypeName and assembly name?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection

I have some classes with names created by convention. I need to retrieve one of them when required. To retrieve a class I need its `AssemblyQualifiedName`. Currently I am using

```
Return Type.GetType("MyAssemblyName." + ClassName, false)
```

I don't like the hardcoded name so I am considering using Name of Assembly `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly.GetName.Name` but it is probably still not precise enough I need `"{MyAssemblyName." + ClassName + ", Version=1.0.5077.23831, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}"`.

**Can I combine a class name with a qualified name of an assembly without necessity of parsing it?**

Note: Question is tagged VB and C# because that code presented and needed is simple enough to be mutually understandable.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't it simply typeof(MyClass).AssemblyQualifiedName?

Comment: @dudeNumber4: I know the name of the class as string e.g. "Foo_M". Compare `typeof(MyClass)` and `typeof("MyClass")`. typeof requires ClassName be known in compile time.

Comment: Your basic question is "how can I get information I don't have?"  You can't.  Especially allowing the [AssemblyVersion] to auto-increment is a major obstacle.  The egg goes before the chicken, you really do need the assembly first.

Comment: @HansPassant: The class is supposed to be present in the calling assembly. So I need something as "Qualify name by given assembly". I know the assembly but I need to combine it with a class name to get the qualified class name (from qualified assembly name and class name).

Comment: Then simply use Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetType() and just pass the type name.

Comment: @HansPassant: It looked promising. But it still [requires full name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/y0cd10tb.aspx). So I am where I was at the begining GetType("MyAssemblyName." + ClassName).

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The namespace name is *always* included with the type name.  You can only ever use a short name in source code with the Imports directive.  If you don't know the namespace name either then you're up a creek without a paddle.

Comment: @HansPassant: I know the namespace. I don't like the the construction 'GetType("MyAssemblyName." + ClassName)` where it is hardcoded or `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetType(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName.Name + "." + ClassName)` which is ugly.

Comment: That's hardcoded as well, there's no guarantee whatsoever that the namespace name of the type matches the assembly display name.  Just rename the DLL to make your code fail.  If you know the namespace name then the smart thing to do is to use it.  If you don't then you don't have a paddle.